# Edit column under condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a table:

```
  id <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5)
  dist <- c(0,1,1,0,2,15,0,4,4,0,5,5,16,2)
  data <- data.frame(id, dist )
```

I would like to edit the column `id` when dist is superior to a certain value (let´s say 10). I am looking to add `+1` when `data$dist >10`

The final output would be:

```
  data$id_new <-  c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7)
```

Is it possible to do something with a `if` loop? I tried to something with a loop but I am still not successful.

Comment: data$id > 10 pr data$dist > 10? question is really not clear.

Comment: I tried to get `max(data$id)` and to add `max(data$id)+1` when `data$dist >10`

Comment: Could you add expected output if the first value of dist is 11?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe using cumsum:

```
data$new_id <- data$id + cumsum(data$dist > 10)
```

**Explanation:**

`cumsum(data$dist > 10)` will return the cumulative sum of indices in `data$dist` which are greater than 10.  You can see how this works by taking the expression apart in R and seeing how each piece works.

Comment: @akrun I think both mine and yours is wrong. Imagine 1st value of dist is 11.

Comment: @zx8754 In that case also `1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 7`  I am not getting what you meant.  I think it starts from 1, right?

Comment: @akrun I think OP is not clear with expected output.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `duplicated` with `>`

```
with(data, cumsum(dist > 10| !duplicated(id)))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 7
```

Comment: Why `!duplicated`?

Comment: @zx8754 Just to capture the `TRUE` when every new ID happens (assuming that the data is ordered.  It should work also with unordered but then I guess the logical in the question should also be changed).  If we are using numeric addition, it could be problematic in a categorical variable.